# Products don't display

Tags: magento2, product, frontend

I've setup a Magento 2.1.2 and things seem to be working fine (categories, attribute sets, etc.).

The first test product though I created a simple product from the default attribute set an had:

- Enable Product: Yes
- Quantity: 100
- Stock status: In Stock
- Categories: MyTest
- Visibility: Catalog,Search
- Websites: Main Website

After saving it, it doesn't show in my category.
Then I ran the cronjob, the indexes got updated and nothing shows up.
Then I flushed the cashes, still nothing on the frontend.
I search for the SKU, nothing shows up as well.
I'm wondering whether I'm missing something?

Comment: Are you on the good website / database ? are you sure of every steps you've described ? It seems you do good. it should have been displayed.

Comment: After diging around, it seems as if the cron jobs don't trigger the re-index process if needed and my admin panel didn't tell me to re-index. So I explicitly called: `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` and now it's working. So I just assumed I ran the index with the crons but actually didn't - sorry for the trouble caused.